# Tether wired internet from Desktop to laptop via wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, internet, desktop-computer, bridge

What I have :

- Desktop, wired internet access to a wired-only router
- Laptop, wireless capable
- Windows 8.1 Preview on both computers - it's practically Windows 8 with some UI touches and performance tweaks

What I would need :

- A device connected to the desktop, as an network proxy (so to say) that would offer wireless access to the laptop (and smartphones etc).
- The wireless network access to be available only when the desktop is running.

Surely, the first thing I hear is "Replace your wired router to a wireless router" **but I don't want for access to be available when the desktop is off**. The reason for my slightly strange request is that I don't want a source of radiation when I sleep or whenever I don't really need WiFi access. I would refrain on arguing on how WiFi is not bad to your health, no research studies bla bla. I just don't want it. If this whole thing **can't** be done so be it, just tell me.

Things that might be useful in my case but don't understand them enough :

- (USB) Wireless bridge
- ICS : Internet Connection Sharing

Thank you!

Comment: what is your desktop OS? check if it can be made into an ad hoc access  point already. mac osx can, so does newer windows. you will need a wireless card or usb wireless adapter on the desktop in that case, if it does not have a builtin one.

Comment: Thanks! So I could just buy a 10$ USB wireless adapter such as http://www.amazon.com/Edimax-EW-7811Un-Wireless-Adapter-Wizard/dp/B003MTTJOY/ref=sr_1_2?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1377107427&sr=1-2&keywords=wireless+usb+adapter and be done with it via Internet Connection Sharing?

Comment: PS : I added OS details in the question.

Comment: yes, you are right. you can find a lot of instructions about windows 8/7 wifi hotspot setup, some even with video.

Comment: On older Windows versions, you could setup Internet Connection Sharing and link two interfaces, so device on the second interface could use the internet connection on the first interface. You were able to do this in Win7 with a wireless adapter, so you probably can in Win8 as well, here are the Win7 steps: http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot

Comment: You could provide the above links as answers so I can upvote them and choose an answer to the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On older Windows versions, you could setup [Internet Connection Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing) and link two interfaces, so a device on the second interface could use the internet connection on the first interface. You were able to do this in Win7 with a wireless adapter, so you probably can in Win8 as well. The Win7 steps are available [here](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot).

Comment: But will a simple wireless network adapter be able to provide network access, that is, act as a hotspot, for the laptop?

Comment: The network adapter in your computer is the same as the device in a wireless router, it is just a wireless antennae that can receive and transmit data - the network adapter itself is really just a conduit for I/O. It is the software that shifts the functionality, so if you configure it right, then yes, it can be a hotspot.

Comment: Alright, I'll go ahead and buy one then (from a shop that allows me to return it in 30 days money back no questions) and start fiddling with it until it works :D